# java enum compile error "unclosed string literal"

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Constants {
    public enum Status{
        sen(3,"发送中"),
        suc(8,"成功"),
        fai(6,"失败"),
        ;
        Integer status;
        String desc;
        Status(String desc, Integer status) {
            this.desc = desc;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public Integer getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Integer status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            this.desc = desc;
        }
    }

}
```

then compile error with this "unclosed string literal" "aftersen(3," .
if I remove variable "desc" then error is disappear.
can someone help me?

Comment: Is your source file's encoding what your `javac` expects?

Comment: Also, consider removing the extraneous comma after enum constant `fai`.

Comment: And you appear to be giving your constructor arguments in the wrong order.  Your constructor expects the string to be first.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good points, except the extra comma at the end: that's allowed.

Comment: I use idea and the encoding is utf-8. I try again,change Chinese to English then the error disppear. The weird thing is that there is another similar enum in the class don't have error . I also think the reason is encoding .

Answer (score 3):

You must be using UTF-8 or something as your file encoding ... so I suspect that the problem is "homoglyphs" in your source code.

More specifically, one of those double-quote characters is not an ASCII double-quote (Unicode 0x0022).  Java only recognizes ASCII double-quote characters as having significance in a String literal.  Other characters that "look like" double-quotes are ... just string content.

Another answer points out that you have the constructor arguments in the wrong order.  That is NOT what causes the "unclosed string literal" error.